# Unique documents in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need to store three id:s in a document but they can only occur once. For example the document below can only occur once in this collection:

```
{
  "user": ObjectId("j8uwh902w5489"),
  "comment": ObjectId("09890583457jkjsf4"),
  "whatever": ObjectId("j8uwh902w5489")
}
```

How do I make sure this will be a unique document in MongoDB?

Comment: I want to know what person will be where and who they work for. That's why I want the combination to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use [MongoDB's Unique Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-compound-index)

```
db.users.createIndex( { user: 1, comment: 1, whatever: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

A few Cases:

```
> db.users.insert({user: "A", comment: "B", whatever: "C"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.insert({user: "A", comment: "C", whatever: "B"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.insert({user: "A", comment: "B", whatever: "C"})
> WriteResult({

    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.users.$user_1_comment_1_whatev
er_1  dup key: { : \"A\", : \"B\", : \"C\" }"
    }
})
```

I know I have used strings here. But something similar might also be possible with ObjectIds. Please do give it a try.

Comment: Doesn't that just make each individual property unique and not the combination? I have tried to save them as `ObjectId()` from adminMongo but for some reason they all get the id from `_id` and not the id I try to save.

Comment: I don't have time to test now but it looks like what I want so I accept it!

Comment: @Oskar If you defined it as a compound index (consists of more than one property), then it ensures the uniqueness of the combination, not each property alone.